# Is const function thread safe

Tags: c++, multithreading

Is reading a non-`mutable` variable from a `const` function thread-safe?

For example, I have a class `DataStore` and `enum SOME_ENUM`:

```
class DataStore
{
   enum SOME_ENUM enum_val;
   std::mutex mutex;

public:
   void SetSomeEnum(SOME_ENUM val);
   SOME_ENUM GetSomeEnumVal() const;
}

void DataStore::SetSomeEnum(SOME_ENUM val)
{
    mutex.lock();
    enum_val = val;
    mutex.unlock();
}

SOME_ENUM DataStore::GetSomeEnumVal() const
{
    return enum_val;
}

DataStore d;
```

Now thread A is updating the value of the enum through `d.SetSomeEnum()` and threads B, C are reading the value through `d.GetSomeEnumVal()`.

Please tell if this implementation is correct and if method `GetSomeEnumVal()` guarantees to return the latest value to all the threads that call it. And are there any race conditions in this implementation?

Comment: Many bad things could happen. It's even conceivable that `GetSomeEnumVal` could execute half way through a write to `enum_val` and get a garbage result. This looks like a good place to try out [`std::atomic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) and [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) or [`std::scoped_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock).

Comment: Thanks for user4581301 for your reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you posted is not thread-safe.  The rule is, if there is any chance that one thread might write to a variable while a second thread is concurrently accessing that same variable (i.e. either writing to it *or* reading it), then your program invokes undefined behavior (due to a race condition) and is not guaranteed to function correctly.

To avoid the race condition, you need to either synchronize the read-access inside `GetSomeEnumVal()` with a mutex (the same way you did with the write-access inside `SetSomeEnum()`) or alternatively change `enum_val` to be an atomic type which is explicitly documented to be able to handle simultaneous unsynchronized access in a well-defined manner.